# Join the data from 2 tables in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables: order and order_product. they look like this

```
 Order table                            order_product
 order_id   customer_id                 order_id      product_name
 1          1                           1             pr1
 2          1                           1             pr2
 3          2                           2             product1
 4          1                           2             product2
                                        3             product1
                                        4             product1
```

I need to get information on the basis of a product. So let us say I search for the orders with product1 (product_name) and ordered by customer 1 (customer_id). How would I perform such a search? Sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm a beginner with the SQL queries...

Comment: What have you tried?  Start by looking up how to use `join`...

Comment: have you taken a SQL tutorial yet which includes the use of a JOIN? If you have, the answer ought to be fairly clear, or at least clear enough for you to make some attempt at it. We're happy to help if you have made some basic effort to solve your own problem first, but it's not clear whether you've even done the most basic research. It's not our job to teach you the very simplest parts of SQL, you can learn that in lots of places already.

Comment: Documentation for doing joins is available here  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html syntax is `select <element> from table t join order_product op on t.order_id = op.order_id`  in many cases you might want to use a left join (see docs)

Comment: I have learnt the basics about the joins. but the problem is that neither of the joins works here. I quess because of that both tables have cross matches, so the simple join query returns the first matched result - 1 row while I need to return multiple rows: all orders where the customer_id = x and product_name = y.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
select o_t.order_id, o_t.customer_id, o_p.product_name from 
(select order_id, customer_id from order_table) o_t,
(select order_id, product_name from order_product where product_name = '{filter}') o_p
where o_t.order_id = o_p.order_id
```

Add your product name based on what you want to search in the `where` clause

Comment: Hi, Sorry this doesn't work either...This is what I have;  "SELECT o.order_id, o.date_added, op.name FROM (SELECT order_id, o.date_added FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order) o, (SELECT order_id, name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product WHERE name LIKE 'bouw%') op WHERE o.order_id = op.order_id";

Comment: @AleksandraChuprova Okay, what output are you getting? It would be helpful if you can give the output

Comment: Thanks again. I have solved the problem. My bad. The query was more complicated than in the question and one of the parameters was incorrect datatype. I should have been integer and it was passed byt he form as a string. When I found it out and got it straight, everything worked out.